# How to increase the request page time in python 3 while scraping web pages?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-crawler, python-requests

I have started scraping reviews from e-commerce platform and perform sentiment analysis and share it with people on my blog to make the life of people easier and understand everything about the product in just one article.
I am using python packages like selenium and bs4. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def remove_non_ascii_1(text):

return ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in text])

with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
    site = "https://www.flipkart.com/honor-8-pro-midnight-black-128-gb/product-reviews/itmeymafrghbjcpf?page=1&pid=MOBEWXHMVYBBMZGJ"
browser.get(site)

file = open("review.txt", "w")

for count in range(1, 100):
    nav_btns = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_33m_Yg')

    button = ""

    for btn in nav_btns:
        number = int(btn.text)
        if(number==count):
            button = btn
            break

    button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_2xg6Ul")))

    read_more_btns = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_1EPkIx')


    for rm in read_more_btns:
        browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", rm)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -150);")
        rm.click()

    page_source = browser.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "lxml")
    ans = soup.find_all("div", class_="_3DCdKt")


    for tag in ans:
        title = str(tag.find("p", class_="_2xg6Ul").string).replace(u"\u2018", "'").replace(u"\u2019", "'")
        title = remove_non_ascii_1(title)
        title.encode('ascii','ignore')
        content = tag.find("div", class_="qwjRop").div.prettify().replace(u"\u2018", "'").replace(u"\u2019", "'")
        content = remove_non_ascii_1(content)
        content.encode('ascii','ignore')
        content = content[15:-7]

        votes = tag.find_all("span", class_="_1_BQL8")
        upvotes = int(votes[0].string)
        downvotes = int(votes[1].string)

        file.write("Review Title : %s\n\n" % title )
        file.write("Upvotes : " + str(upvotes) + "\n\nDownvotes : " + str(downvotes) + "\n\n")
        file.write("Review Content :\n%s\n\n\n\n" % content )

file.close()
```

The code is working fine on platform like Amazon, but on Flipkart, after crawling 14 pages I get an error saying "Someting is Wrong!!!" and the crawling stops.
In command line I get this error:

> C:\Users\prate\Desktop\Crawler\Git_Crawler\New>python scrape.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "scrape.py", line 37, in 
>       WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_2xg6Ul")))
>     File "C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

There is no message printed as well. I think if I increase the request time interval on the platform it might let me crawl. 
What should I do?

Comment: If you sure that element should be present on page and you just need more time to wait for it appearance, then replace timeout `10` in `WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_2xg6Ul")))` to, for example, `20`

Comment: Thanks Andersson, but it did not work. I get this error after 14 pages are scraped, check link: https://ibb.co/egBpGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
C:\Users\prate\Desktop\Crawler\Git_Crawler\New>python scrape.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "scrape.py", line 37, in WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_2xg6Ul"))) File "C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

If you look at the *API Docs* of the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause [`presence_of_all_elements_located(locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located) it is defined as :

```
An expectation for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page. locator is used to find the element returns the list of WebElements once they are located
```

Now, if you browse to the intended webpage :

```
https://www.flipkart.com/honor-8-pro-midnight-black-128-gb/product-reviews/itmeymafrghbjcpf?page=1&pid=MOBEWXHMVYBBMZGJ
```

You will find the *webpage* have **no products or reviews** and the [*Locator Strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have adapted as **(By.CLASS_NAME, "_2xg6Ul")** doesn't identifies any element on the webpage.

[image: no_products_reviews_elements]

Hence even though the synchronization time elapses, no *webelements* are added to the **list** and **selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException** is raised.

As you mentioned *The code is working fine on platform like Amazon* it is worth to mention that the website `https://www.flipkart.com` is **ReactJS** based and may differ from *website* to *website*

Comment: Thanks Debanjan for answering this. I looked into the this and found actually there was no review on flipkart page 15, but there is one more thing, they say they have 155 pages of review but most of the pages dont show any review and if I go on page 20, once it will show nothing on the page, but if I again go on the page after trying 3-4 other pages, it will show the review there. I did not get this thing, and what should I do to make a perfect crawler for flipkart?

Comment: I was wondering what should I be writing as the title of the problem I am facing in the new question? Is there any technical term for it? There is no pattern here. If I keep on refreshing review page 15 or 20 or 51, 2 times of 10 times I might get the data (the reviews) or I might get it after 5 refresh, etc.